# Removing volume control in video html player

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-video

I am wondering how can I remove the video volume control from an HTML player?
As it is stated in the [api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video), the `controlslist`attribute's allowed values are `nodownload`, `nofullscreen` and `noremoteplayback`. And since I would like to implement a sound volume controller outside of the player.

```
    <video
      width="100%"
      src={mediaModel.url}
      onContextMenu={disableEvent}
      controlsList="nodownload"
      onPlay={() => onVideoPlay()}
      onEnded={() => onVideoEnded()}
      controls
      disablePictureInPicture
    />
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

An easy solution for that is to hide the button using css:

```css
video::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider {
  display: none;
}

video::-webkit-media-controls-mute-button {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<video width="100%" src='' controlsList="nodownload" controls disablePictureInPicture />
```

Comment: There is still when you hover over visible placeholder for volume slider

Comment: It works only on webkit browser. It doesn't work mozila firefox, i.e